# How to dynamically change the table schema while reading csv data in BQ?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bq

I have data in txt format with several files, each file has 3 columns and few files have 4 columns, how do create the table which will only read 1st 3 columns?

i have been using BQ UI for creating tables, this is causing error when reading data with 4 columns,

EX : file1.txt

```
1234|sample|test
1254|sample2|test2
12324|sample3|test3
```

File2.txt

```
1234|var1|test
1254|var2|test2
12324|var3|test3
```

file3.txt

```
1234|var1|test|123242
1254|var2|test2|1321412
12324|var3|test3|1312123
```

Schema i have now is

```
field1 Int
field2 String
field3 String
filed4 Int
```

i have these file in gcs bucket and the external table is pointed to this location,

> Error while reading table:
> testing-dataset-project.testing_tables.test_data, error message:
> CSV table references column position 3, but line starting at
> position:0 contains only 3 columns.

Comment: also paste here your code

Comment: i am not using any code to create table, i am using Google BQ UI, i am adding the schema there manually

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option `Allow jagged rows` as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#csv-options).